# My excel file has more than 30_000 rows but the confusion matrix gives less records

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

My excel file has more than 30_000 rows but the confusion matrix is only showing:

```
[[   1  282]
 [   2 5821]]
```

To have my file read by python I used:

```py
uitkeringen = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Gubbels\Documents\Python Scripts\Data\KNN algoritme\20210226 De KNN-Dataset v1.1.xlsx')
```

Comment: What does `uitkeringen.shape` return?

Comment: You need to provide some minimal working example of your code.